# Windows 8 Store Apps — which type of storage to use?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm a little bit confused over the various types of storage that is available to Windows Store Apps.

Let's say I had a notepad app, where users can view, create, and edit notes. What storage type would I use for storing the notes? Local storage? Write the notes out to files in the user's Documents folder? Also, what if I wanted to sync a user's notes via the cloud? I understand that Roaming Data has a rather low size limit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Almost all the options you mention are possible for a notepad application. Except the roaming data option, that only allows you to store 100KB of data.

I will try to sum up the options that you have and add a few more:

**Localstorage**
You can easily add these files to [localstorage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh700361%28v=win.10%29.aspx), you can store it in file format or serialize your object and store that one. Very easy to implement. Con is that only your app can access these files.

**Documents folder**
Also an option. Made easy by use of different filepickers. For example the [FileOpenPicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker.aspx) or the [FileSavePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.filesavepicker.aspx). Files can be stored in the format you like and can be accessed by other apps or through the file explorer.

**Roaming data**
No option for files due too the limited space

**Skydrive API**
If you want to store files in the Cloud and access them anywhere you could consider the [skydrive api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/live/hh826521.aspx). Also note that if you use the filepickers you also have the option to save/load these files to skydrive. (Although in that case the user chooses where to store the file.)

**Windows Azure Mobile Services**
Another option if you want to store data in the cloud. Gives you the ability to store your data in a table/tables. Very easy to implement. More info about mobile services can be found [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-data-dotnet/)

**SQL Lite**
If you need a local database to store your data than SQLLite can be an option. Tim Heuer has wrote a nice blogpost about how to use SQLLite in your windows 8 app. You can find it [here](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/05/20/using-sqlite-in-metro-style-app.aspx)

Hopefully this clears up things a bit and gives you some ideas about what to choose for your app?

Comment: add Windows Azure Mobile Services (if cloud makes sense here) and SQLite locally. SQLite has a full-text search capability (that I believe should be available in Windows Store apps) which could provide a great feature in such an app.

Comment: ESENT is also a choice...the managed layer (found here: http://managedesent.codeplex.com/) makes it a heck of a lot more approachable for most Win8 devs.

Answer (score 1):

In an app like this (a notepad style app), the logical place to store you files in in the user's documents folder.  That way they are accessible to the user from other apps as well as the current one.  There is, of course, the option to roll your own methods to upload the data to SkyDrive as well, but you really shouldn't rely on this as being your only data source - what if the user is offline?