# System.Data.Common.DbConnection could not be resolved in my win 8 app

Tags: visual-studio, ms-access, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Something really strange...i'm trying to having access to a mdb file in my win 8 app.
this is my simple code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.OleDb;

 string strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Assets/File.mdb";
 string strSQL = "SELECT CF FROM Comuni WHERE Comune = '" + m_strComNasc + "'";
 OleDbConnection myConn = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
 OleDbCommand myCmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, myConn);
 myConn.Open();
 OleDbDataReader myReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader();
 if (myReader.Read())
      strConn = myReader.GetString(0);
 else
      strConn = "";

 myReader.Close();
 myConn.Close();
```

In Solution Explorer References i've done add Reference and selected "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.dll"...

These are the errors:

```
The base class or interface 'System.ComponentModel.Component' in assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' referenced by type 'System.Data.Common.DbConnection' could not be resolved    c:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.dll

The base class or interface 'System.ComponentModel.Component' in assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' referenced by type 'System.Data.Common.DbCommand' could not be resolved   c:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.dll

The base class or interface 'System.MarshalByRefObject' in assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' referenced by type 'System.Data.Common.DbDataReader' could not be resolved    c:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.dll
```

Comment: in my Control Panel: System Type: 32-bit Operating System, x64-based processor. Can i use my .mdb file?Have i completely change my code?

Comment: [Windows 8 Store Apps — which type of storage to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953940/windows-8-store-apps-which-type-of-storage-to-use)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use ADO.Net in Metro (Windows Store) Apps. If you look at the [.NET for Windows Store apps - supported APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230232.aspx) page, you will see that the `System.Data` namespace is absent.

Comment: interesting...now which alternatives i have?someone give me the .mdb file, can i use it?or they have to send me something else?

Comment: @CaptainAmerica - Windows Store apps currently support only Sqlite and Index Db. If you want to use an Access db, you must create a normal Desktop .Net Application.