# what compliments sql-azure for offline scenarios?

Tags: azure, windows-runtime

I'm looking at using a database on Azure for my next application, but I'm wondering what if my user(s) don't have an internet connection?  What is a good compliment to save the data locally until the internet connection is re-established?

Comment: When you say `Users`, do you mean the end users of your application or do you mean the developers in your team? What kind of application are you building - web/desktop?

Comment: I am building a Windows 8 Application that will be available in the store.

Comment: Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953940/windows-8-store-apps-which-type-of-storage-to-use. It has some nice options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look into the [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753.aspx).

It would allow you to use a SQL Server Compact database on your local application, and then sync with a SQL Server instance when in online mode.

The MS Press Book for MCTS 70-516 has a chapter section on utilizing the Sync Framework.
[Accessing Data with Microsoft .NET Framework 4](http://dl.it-college.org/download/ebook/microsoft/70-516.pdf) - Page 561

Comment: [Sql ce is not supported in Windows Store (Windows Runtime) apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909202/do-windows-8-metro-style-application-support-sql-server-ce-local-database).